# Load webform handler to change to_mail

Tags: webforms, 9

I have a contact form with three handlers, on to send mail to admin, second to sales team and the last one to the one who have filled out the form.

I would like to change the to_mail address programatically, config sync is not allowed.

Is there any way to load webform handler and set the to address programatically.

```
function efx_send_mail_update_9953() {
 $config = \Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('webform.webform.contact'); // contact is the webform
 print_r($config);
 //die;
 $config_key = 'handlers.email_confirmation.to_mail'; // email_confirmation is the handler
 $config->set($config_key, '123@gmail.com')->save();*/
}
```

Comment: Google: https://gist.github.com/mamesaye/1be4dd33ba37f33e661f0a3434de2f52

Comment: Thank you. it worked for me.